# while loading excel data into database using servlets ( java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Workbook)

Tags: java, excel, servlets

I am getting java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Workbook by using poi-3.16 library jar files,can anyone help me to solve this issue.

**UploadExcel(Servlet)**
(this is used to call the methods of UploadDao class based on UploadBean class object)

```
    import java.io.File;
    import java.io.FileInputStream;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.sql.Connection;
    import java.sql.DriverManager;
    import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
    import java.sql.SQLException;
    import java.util.Iterator;
    import java.util.List;

    import javax.servlet.ServletException;
    import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
    import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
    import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

    import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFSheet;
    import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook;
    import org.apache.poi.poifs.filesystem.POIFSFileSystem;
    import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;
    import org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.FileItem;
    import org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.FileItemFactory;
    import org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.FileUploadException;
    import org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.RequestContext;
    import org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.disk.DiskFileItemFactory;
    import org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.servlet.ServletFileUpload;
    import org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.servlet.ServletRequestContext;

    import com.model.dao.UploadDao;
    import com.mvc.bean.UploadBean;
    import com.upload.excel.InsertDataToDB;

    import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;

    @WebServlet("/UploadExcel")
    public class UploadExcel extends HttpServlet {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
                throws ServletException, IOException {

            boolean isMultipart = ServletFileUpload.isMultipartContent(request);

            if (isMultipart) {
                // Create a factory for disk-based file items
                FileItemFactory factory = new DiskFileItemFactory();

                // Create a new file upload handler
                ServletFileUpload upload = new ServletFileUpload(factory);

                try {
                    // Parse the request
                    List /* FileItem */ items = upload.parseRequest(new ServletRequestContext(request));
                    Iterator iterator = items.iterator();
                    while (iterator.hasNext()) {
                        FileItem item = (FileItem) iterator.next();
                        if (!item.isFormField()) {
                            String fileName = item.getName();
                            System.out.println(fileName);
                            String fileN = fileName.substring(fileName.lastIndexOf("\\") + 1);
                            System.out.println(fileN);
                            // String root = getServletContext().getRealPath("/");
                            String root1 = "E:/eclipse/workspace/GSTR_Test0/WebContent";
                            File path = new File(root1 + "/uploads");
                            if (!path.exists()) {
                                boolean status = path.mkdirs();
                            }

                            File uploadedFile = new File(path + "/" + fileN);
                            System.out.println(uploadedFile.getAbsolutePath());
                            item.write(uploadedFile);
                            String filePath = uploadedFile.toString();
                            UploadBean uploadbean = new UploadBean();
                            uploadbean.setFilepath(filePath);

                            // creating object for uploadDao class and calling
                            // methods in it
                            UploadDao uploadDao = new UploadDao();
                            boolean b = uploadDao.getDataFromExcel();
                            if (b == true) {
                                System.out.println("excel data is assigned to bean class");
                            } else {
                                System.out.println("unable to assign data to bean class");
                            }
                            String s = uploadDao.uploadDataToDB(uploadbean);
                            if (s.equals("SUCCESS")) {
                                System.out.println("data inserted successfully into DB");
                            } else {
                                System.out.println(" unable to insert data into DB");
                            }

                        }
                    }
                } catch (FileUploadException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

        }

    }
```

**UploadDao**(it has two methods, reads data from uploaded excel file and sets the file cell values to UploadBean class object and gets the value from same bean class in another method)

```
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Sheet;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Workbook;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;

import com.db.util.DBConnection;

import com.mvc.bean.UploadBean;

public class UploadDao {

    public boolean getDataFromExcel() {
        // List excel = new ArrayList();
        FileInputStream fis = null;
        UploadBean uploadbean = new UploadBean();
        String FILE_PATH = uploadbean.getFilepath();
        try {
            fis = new FileInputStream(FILE_PATH);

            // Using XSSF for xlsx format, for xls use HSSF
            Workbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(fis);

            int numberOfSheets = workbook.getNumberOfSheets();

            // looping over each workbook sheet
            for (int i = 0; i < numberOfSheets; i++) {
                Sheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(i);
                Iterator rowIterator = sheet.iterator();

                // iterating over each row
                while (rowIterator.hasNext()) {

                    Row row = (Row) rowIterator.next();
                    Iterator cellIterator = row.cellIterator();

                    // Iterating over each cell (column wise) in a particular
                    // row.
                    while (cellIterator.hasNext()) {

                        Cell cell = (Cell) cellIterator.next();
                        // The Cell Containing String will is name.
                        if (Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING == cell.getCellType()) {
                            uploadbean.setSupplyplace(cell.getStringCellValue());
                            // The Cell Containing numeric value will contain
                            // marks
                        } else if (Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC == cell.getCellType()) {

                            // Cell with index 1 contains marks in Maths
                            if (cell.getColumnIndex() == 0) {
                                uploadbean.setSerialno(cell.getNumericCellValue());
                            }
                            // Cell with index 2 contains marks in Science
                            else if (cell.getColumnIndex() == 1) {
                                uploadbean.setGstin(cell.getNumericCellValue());
                            }
                            // Cell with index 3 contains marks in English
                            else if (cell.getColumnIndex() == 2) {
                                uploadbean.setInvoiceno(cell.getNumericCellValue());
                            } else if (cell.getColumnIndex() == 3) {
                                uploadbean.setInvoicedate(cell.getNumericCellValue());
                            } else if (cell.getColumnIndex() == 4) {
                                uploadbean.setInvoicevalue(cell.getNumericCellValue());
                            } else if (cell.getColumnIndex() == 5) {
                                uploadbean.setRate(cell.getNumericCellValue());
                            } else if (cell.getColumnIndex() == 6) {
                                uploadbean.setTaxablevalue(cell.getNumericCellValue());
                            } else if (cell.getColumnIndex() == 7) {
                                uploadbean.setIntegratedtax(cell.getNumericCellValue());
                            } else if (cell.getColumnIndex() == 8) {
                                uploadbean.setCentraltax(cell.getNumericCellValue());
                            } else if (cell.getColumnIndex() == 9) {
                                uploadbean.setStatetax(cell.getNumericCellValue());
                            } else if (cell.getColumnIndex() == 10) {
                                uploadbean.setCess(cell.getNumericCellValue());
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    // end iterating a row, add all the elements of a row in
                    // list
                    // studentList.add(student);
                }
            }

            fis.close();

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return true;
    }

    public String uploadDataToDB(UploadBean uploadBean) {

        double serialNo = uploadBean.getSerialno();
        double gstin = uploadBean.getGstin();
        double invoiceNo = uploadBean.getInvoiceno();
        double invoiceDate = uploadBean.getInvoicedate();
        double invoiceValue = uploadBean.getInvoicevalue();
        double rate = uploadBean.getRate();
        double taxableValue = uploadBean.getTaxablevalue();
        double integratedTax = uploadBean.getIntegratedtax();
        double centralTax = uploadBean.getCentraltax();
        double stateTax = uploadBean.getStatetax();
        double cess = uploadBean.getCess();
        String supplyPlace = uploadBean.getSupplyplace();

        Connection conn = null;
        PreparedStatement preparedstatement = null;
        try {
            conn = DBConnection.createConnection();
            String query = "insert into table4a(gstin,invoiceno,invoicedate,invoicevalue,rate,taxablevalue,integratedtax,centraltax,statetax,cess,supplyplace) values(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)"; // Insert
                                                                                                                                                                                                // user
                                                                                                                                                                                                // details
                                                                                                                                                                                                // into
                                                                                                                                                                                                // the
                                                                                                                                                                                                // table
                                                                                                                                                                                                // 'registration'
            preparedstatement = conn.prepareStatement(query); // Making use of
                                                                // prepared
                                                                // statements
                                                                // here to
                                                                // insert bunch
                                                                // of data

            preparedstatement.setDouble(1, gstin);
            preparedstatement.setDouble(2, invoiceNo);
            preparedstatement.setDouble(3, invoiceDate);
            preparedstatement.setDouble(4, invoiceValue);
            preparedstatement.setDouble(5, rate);
            preparedstatement.setDouble(6, taxableValue);
            preparedstatement.setDouble(7, integratedTax);
            preparedstatement.setDouble(8, centralTax);
            preparedstatement.setDouble(9, stateTax);
            preparedstatement.setDouble(10, cess);
            preparedstatement.setString(11, supplyPlace);

            int i = preparedstatement.executeUpdate();
            if (i != 0) // Just to ensure data has been inserted into the
                        // database
                return "SUCCESS";
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return "This data was already uploaded by you";

    }

}
```

**UploadBean**

```
import java.io.File;
import javax.servlet.http.Part;

public class UploadBean {
    private String filepath;
    private File file;
    private double serialno;
    private double gstin;
    private double invoiceno;
    private double invoicedate;
    private double invoicevalue;
    private double rate;
    private double taxablevalue;
    private double Integratedtax;
    private double centraltax;
    private double statetax;
    private double cess;
    private String supplyplace;

    public File getFile() {
        return file;
    }

    public void setFile(File file) {
        this.file = file;
    }

    public String getFilepath() {
        return filepath;
    }

    public void setFilepath(String filepath) {
        this.filepath = filepath;
    }

    public double getSerialno() {
        return serialno;
    }

    public void setSerialno(double serialno) {
        this.serialno = serialno;
    }

    public double getGstin() {
        return gstin;
    }

    public void setGstin(double gstin) {
        this.gstin = gstin;
    }

    public double getInvoiceno() {
        return invoiceno;
    }

    public void setInvoiceno(double invoiceno) {
        this.invoiceno = invoiceno;
    }

    public double getInvoicedate() {
        return invoicedate;
    }

    public void setInvoicedate(double invoicedate) {
        this.invoicedate = invoicedate;
    }

    public double getInvoicevalue() {
        return invoicevalue;
    }

    public void setInvoicevalue(double invoicevalue) {
        this.invoicevalue = invoicevalue;
    }

    public double getRate() {
        return rate;
    }

    public void setRate(double rate) {
        this.rate = rate;
    }

    public double getTaxablevalue() {
        return taxablevalue;
    }

    public void setTaxablevalue(double taxablevalue) {
        this.taxablevalue = taxablevalue;
    }

    public double getIntegratedtax() {
        return Integratedtax;
    }

    public void setIntegratedtax(double Integratedtax) {
        this.Integratedtax = Integratedtax;
    }

    public double getCentraltax() {
        return centraltax;
    }

    public void setCentraltax(double centraltax) {
        this.centraltax = centraltax;
    }

    public double getStatetax() {
        return statetax;
    }

    public void setStatetax(double statetax) {
        this.statetax = statetax;
    }

    public double getCess() {
        return cess;
    }

    public void setCess(double cess) {
        this.cess = cess;
    }

    public String getSupplyplace() {
        return supplyplace;
    }

    public void setSupplyplace(String supplyplace) {
        this.supplyplace = supplyplace;
    }
}
```

**Exception**

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Workbook
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1892)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1735)
    at UploadExcel.doPost(UploadExcel.java:77)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:650)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:218)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:110)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:506)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:169)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:962)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:445)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1115)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:637)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:316)
```

Comment: is it added to classpath?

Comment: Yes, it is added to classpath

Comment: how did you add it? show the code producing the error

Comment: Are you sure you're only loading one version of Poi?  Is it in your war WEB-INF/lib folder (as opposed to tomcat libs)?

Comment: I am using POI-3.16, added same version of jars to classpath